# live effects using usb on mixer

Tags: effects, live

I have a behringer Q1202USB mixer for live gigs.  It has a USB port and can use it for recording etc.  Is there a way to use the USB port with software or plugin to get reverb or other effects for live gigs????
I tried asking behringer but have not got any answer from any of the emails.

Comment: You can use the mixer as an interface and assign software effects yet latency is really an issue for these mixers as they were not designed for this purpose. Look for a dedicated audio interface and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the spec you can only get the stereo channel via, so would only be useful for adding mix bus effects such as compression, limiters and EQ.

Source:

http://www.music-group.com/Categories/Behringer/Mixers/Analog-Mixers/Q1202USB/p/P0ALQ

> Built-in stereo USB/Audio Interface to connect directly to your
>   computer. Free audio recording, editing and podcasting software plus
>   150 instrument/effect plug-ins downloadable at behringer.com

Have you tried the free software included?

Answer (score 0):

If it was plugged into a laptop and connected to a Daw you could get the effects from a DAW
You'll have to test latency though.